# How to search and extract emails in a data-set using java in my local machine not in the server

Tags: java, email

I have a data-set of 1000 emails, I want to access this data-set from a folder in my laptop and search through all the emails one by one using java, I am using sublime text to code and I am not allowed to use any advanced IDE. How can I go about it?

> > > What I am trying to achieve is similar to how one searches in gmail and relevant emails are shown.

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

The dataset I have received is a Zip file, in which is a folder called `Data` in which .eml files are present.

Comment: how are the emails stored?

Comment: I have been provided with a data-set which is in an email format.

Comment: .. what KIND of email format... eml? txt? pst? .db?

Comment: its called Data_set...kindly look at it... 

click on the link below


>>>>http://scopicafrica.com/mageto/data/

Comment: Okay, first of all, open up those .eml files and you'll see that they are glorified text files. http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0458.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.4-oth-JPR) for reading emails into String form. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39847426/7584363) post will help you.
once you have "String" you can use search algorithms(e.g [Rabin-Karp](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-3-rabin-karp-algorithm/))